# How to anchor with <option> tag in HTML?

Tags: html, tags, anchor, html-select

I'm trying to anchor a div with an option tag but it doesn't work, what´s wrong with my code? Here´s the anchor snippet

```
<select>
        <option value="#b1">1 test</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div id="b1">Testing!</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to make the browser scroll down to the div wth the associated id when an opton is selection in the select list?

Comment: yes, I tried value because id would'nt work and option doesn't allow child elements

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/V99U8/1/)**

```
<select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
   <option value="#b1">1 test</option>
   <option value="#b2">2 test</option>
   <option value="#b3">3 test</option>
</select>

<div id="b1">Testing 1</div>
...
<div id="b2">Testing 2</div>
...
<div id="b3">Testing 3</div>
...
```

Comment: A simple way of doing it, without using any Javascript, perfect.

Comment: But what if you want to ignore the first option?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add an onchange handler to the select element.

function scrollTo(elmt)
    {
        $(elmt.options[elmt.selectedIndex].value).scrollTo(); //With Prototype
    }

To your select, add onchange=scrollTo()

Comment: yeah, it should. i assume you are OK with using Javascript....or do u want a pure HTML solution?

Comment: Javascript is ok if the code works on ie6 too.
About the code, I've just tried it with that function but it didnt work, ill post the code I tried as an answer.

Comment: Bet you ignored the bit about needing to use Prototype