# html - how to compose href based on selection menu

Tags: html, href

How to compose web address based on selection menu?

The desired link should be composed of choosen values, for instance, "https://www.Opel_Volvo.com"

In the provided code, I need to change

```
  action="https://www.lipsum.com"
```

for a string composed of selected possibilities.

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>CAR</h1>
<form
  target="_blank"
  action="https://www.lipsum.com"
  method="get"
>

  <label for="car1">Choose a car 1:</label>
  <select id="car1" name="car1">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select><br><br>

  <label for="car2">Choose a car 2:</label>
  <select id="car2" name="car2">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select><br><br>


  <input type='submit' value='OK'>

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

**After advice**

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far.  Also are you wanting this server side using something like PHP or client-side using javascript ?

Comment: I provided a code that opens a webpage after clicking on OK. My question is how to compose the string after action from selected options. I do not want to use something like PHP or client-side using javascript; just open a different web page based on selection.

Comment: If you want to manipulate Dom object you should use Javascript on client side or a language like php on server side.

Comment: The select does not work that way.  The closes you can come is in these two posts  [Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827038/how-to-anchor-with-option-tag-in-html)  and  [Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309299/select-option-with-anchor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to add `input` event listener to the `select` elements, and set the `action` attribute of `form` accordingly.

```js
let sel1 = document.querySelector("#car1");
let sel2 = document.querySelector("#car2");
let form = document.querySelector("form");

[sel1, sel2].forEach(s =>{
  s.addEventListener("input", ()=>{
    let url = `https://www.${sel1.value}_${sel2.value}.com`;
    form.setAttribute("action", url)
    console.log(form.action)
  })
})
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1>CAR</h1>
<form
  target="_blank"
  action="https://www.lipsum.com"
  method="get"
>

  <label for="car1">Choose a car 1:</label>
  <select id="car1" name="car1">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select><br><br>

  <label for="car2">Choose a car 2:</label>
  <select id="car2" name="car2">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select><br><br>

  <input type='submit' value='OK'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also the OP has said no PHP and no javascript

Comment: @RohitGupta I do not mind. I am a beginner and I imagine this is easier than it really is.

Comment: @TechySharnav The first part should be in another file? Or this is whole .HTML code?

Comment: Note that in its current form, if neither of the `select` elements are interacted with, clicking the OK button will navigate to initial value of `action` (i.e. `https://www.lipsum.com`) instead of a URL based on the default values of the `select` elements (i.e. `https://www.volvo_volvo.com`).

Comment: @ElenaGreg You can use a `<script>` tag and put the JavaScript code inside it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to achieve this.

You could use Javascript to change the url of the form action. Something like:

```
<select id="car1" name="car1" onchange="document.forms[0].setAttribute('action','https://'+car1.value+'_'+car2.value+'.com'">
...
```

Or you could send the form data to a php script which redirects the user to the desired site.

Or you could use redirects in your .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 303 https://www.lipsum.com?car1=opel&car2=volvo https://www.Opel_Volvo.com
```

Comment: How is this different to the previous answer ? Also the OP has said no PHP and no javascript